# python tuple compare with specific number

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, permutation

I have this piece of code

```
import itertools
 
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 
per = itertools.permutations(values, 2)

hyp = 3
 
for val in per:
    print(*val)
```

Output:

```
1 2  
1 3  
1 4  
2 1  
2 3  
2 4  
3 1  
3 2  
3 4  
4 1  
4 2  
4 3
```

I want to compare each tuple with value of hyp (e.g. 3). If each tuple has value less than or equal to hyp it keeps it and if condition doesn't meet, It discard it.
In this case the tuples (4,1),(4,2),(4,3) should be removed.

in other words,
Based on hyp value it takes pair.
If hyp =2 then from value list it output should be like this

```
1 2  
1 3  
1 4  
2 1  
2 3  
2 4
```

I am not sure whether i explained my problem clearly or not. Let me know if it is unclear.

Comment: hi there! can u specify more clearly what u meant with each tuple has value less than or equal to hyp? a tuple has 2 values and hyp 1. how is that comparison going to be performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.  You just need to extract the zero index of each tuple and compare it to hyp:

```
import itertools
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
per = itertools.permutations(values, 2)
hyp = 3
for tup in per:
   if tup[0] <= hyp:
        print(*tup)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't make any difference, gives the same output